# Sistering 2x8 joists to existing 2x6 under pitched roof

Tags: joists, structural

We are going to be remodeling our attic to create 2 extra bedrooms and a living space.

Currently there are only 2x6 joist in the attic.  We are being told that we should sister 2x8s against the existing 2x6 to give more strength.  There is a ceiling with plaster under those 2x6 joists.  So our extra 2" would be coming out of the top of the joist.  Is it ok to cut the ends of the joists to match the roof pitch so the joist can slide under and rest on the sill?

Comment: You will need to cut the ends so they are supported on the wall doing this will not weaken the 2x8 .

Comment: There is a code on how much that is but I can't get a copy on the answer